# Python pandas module openpxyl version issue

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, versions

My installed version of the python(2.7) module pandas (0.14.0) will not import. The message I receive is this:

UserWarning: Installed openpyxl is not supported at this time. Use >=1.6.1 and <2.0.0.

Here's the problem - I already have openpyxl version 1.8.6 installed so I can't figure out what the problem might be! Does anybody know where the issue may lie? Do I need a different combination of versions?

Comment: fixed in pandas 0.14.1, but if you actually have openpyxl installed for 1.8.6 it wouldn't show up (so what I am saying is can your python find it properly?)

Comment: Ah ok. Issue does indeed disappear with 0.14.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to remove the version of openpyxl you installed and let Pandas take care.